# Tab from Cell to Combobox, From cell to cell

Tags: excel, vba

I made a document in Excel where I want the user to Tab through the cells and Combo boxes to fill out.

The solution would be easy if I could use data validation but this does not allow for auto fill.

I figured out how to tab from combobox to combobox

```
Private Sub CBO0_KeyDown(ByVal Keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal shift As Integer)
If Keycode = 9 Then
    CBO1.Activate
End If
End Sub
```

I also figured out how to Tab from Combobox to Cell.

```
Private Sub CBO1_KeyDown(ByVal Keycode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal shift As Integer)
If Keycode = 9 Then
    Range("D10").Activate
End If
End Sub
```

What is left is,

- Cell to combobox
- Cell to Cell

I need the Cell to Cell solution to be in VBA because the solution in Excel doesn't work between Comboboxes and Cells.

To give an idea of the Tab order,

- Combobox
- Combobox
- Cell
- Cell (Line down)
- Cell (line down)
- Combobox
- Cell
- Cell (Line down)
- Cell (line down)
  Repeat

I can not change the order or the whole form won't work.

Comment: I think you will need to look at the `Worksheet Change` event which is triggered when you change a cell.

Comment: I tried a few things in that even a combination of events but the closest i got was that when tabing to the cell or clicking on the cell the focus was directly placed on the combobox. Do you have an example of a code i could try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming these are activeX comboboxes on the worksheet. Using the worksheet_change event, change A1 and the combobox1 will be activated, change combobox1 and B1 will be selected, change B1 and Combobox2 will be activated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then Me.ComboBox2.DropDown

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Me.Range("B1").Select

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Click()
    Me.Range("C1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it is ActiveX, I have to go now but I will give this a go on Monday and mark it answered if it works. thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: Why not see if it works now? I didn't wait until Monday to answer your question.

Comment: I am sorry I really had something important to attend. I just tried on change event. Now if i type something in "A1" then press tab, the dropdown in the combobox is opened but the combobox is not selected. I changed .dropdown to .Activate and now it does what i need. However If no changes are made to A1 it does not tab to the combobox. I will see if i can find a solution for that and post it. Thank you for the on Click event as well that was a nice improvement.

Comment: I figured it out. gonna post my solution later today. thanks for the help !